# SQL - How to optimize a join between two dates?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

I am currently working on a project that would provide monthly information on active insurance policies. Visualization will be done in tableau. The data looks something like this:

```
Policy  Policy Sequence #    Effective Date    Expiration Date    $ amount     Record Insert Date
 a       0                    Jan-20            May-20             $1,000.00    1/1/2020
 a       0                    Jan-20            May-20             $1,500.00    1/1/2020
 a       1                    Jun-20            Dec-20             $2,000.00    6/1/2020
 a       2                    Jan-21            Feb-21             $2,500.00    1/1/2021
```

The table contains millions of active policies for each month, and each has sequence numbers that can repeat due to entry errors. For each policy / sequence number combination, I grab the most recently inserted record using qualify.

Since I am trying to visualize monthly data, I need to break the date ranges up so there is a monthly date containing $ amount for whichever policy version was active at that time. Also, policy / sequence number can be dropped at this point, so we sum everything together. Example of target dataset below:

```
Month   $ amount
Jan-20  $1,500.00
Feb-20  $1,500.00
Mar-20  $1,500.00
Apr-20  $1,500.00
May-20  $1,500.00
Jun-20  $2,000.00  <- Policy change here
Jul-20  $2,000.00
Aug-20  $2,000.00
Sep-20  $2,000.00
Oct-20  $2,000.00
Nov-20  $2,000.00
Dec-20  $2,000.00
Jan-21  $2,500.00  <- Here
Feb-21  $2,500.00
Mar-21  $2,500.00
```

So far, I have joined the policy table above to a base date table containing a single column of month / year dates. Base date table looks like this:

```
Month
1/1/2020
2/1/2020
3/1/2020
...
```

Full SQL here:

```
select
B.Date1, 
ContractingFirm,
StateCode,
sum(PolicyCount) as PolicyCount, 
sum(DollarAmount) as DollarAmount

from BaseTable B
    join
    (
    select 
    PolicyNumber,
    PolicySequence,
    InsertDate,
    date_trunc(month, EffectiveDate) as EffectiveDate, 
    date_trunc(month, ExpirationDate) as ExpirationDate, 
    sum(1) as PolicyCount, 
    sum(DollarAmount) as DollarAmount, 
   
    from Policy_Table
    group by 
    PolicyNumber, 
    PolicySequence,
    InsertDate,
    EffectiveDate,
    ExpirationDate

    qualify row_number() over (partition by PolicyNumber, PolicySequence order by InsertDate desc) = 1

    ) PolicyTable on Date1 between PolicyTable.EffectiveDate and PolicyTable.ExpirationDate

where B.Date1 between '2020-01-01' and '2021-03-01'

group by 
B.Date1, 
ContractingFirm,
StateCode
```

This query is EXTREMELY slow. It seems like the join is where the slow down occurs, it takes 5-10 minutes to run for a single month. The dollar amounts also go into the trillions for thousands of rows, not sure if that could be an issue? Does anyone have any ideas on how to optimize this? I feel like there has to be a better way to iterate the months into separate lines instead of using a that join!

Thank you for reading :D

Comment: `SUM(1)` - that's an odd way to do `COUNT(*)`... Job security by obscurity?

Comment: Ha! Honestly just not the best at SQL, so sometimes do things in odd ways!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to summarize the data that doesn't fall between your start and end dates, so don't include those rows. You also don't really need a table of dates if you use the [array_generate_range](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_generate_range) function. Something like this (not exact as you don't indicate where ContractingFirm and StateCode originate):

```
with t0 as (
    select
        '2020-01-01' as start_date,
        '2021-03-01' as end_date,
        datediff("months", start_date, end_date) + 1 range
), t1(bdate1) as (
    select dateadd("months", a.index, t0.start_date)
    from t0, lateral flatten(array_generate_range(0, t0.range)) a
), t2 as (
select 
    PolicyNumber,
    PolicySequence,
    InsertDate,
    date_trunc(month, EffectiveDate) as EffectiveDate, 
    date_trunc(month, ExpirationDate) as ExpirationDate, 
    sum(1) as PolicyCount, 
    sum(DollarAmount) as DollarAmount, 
    from Policy_Table join t1
    on t1.bdate1 between EffectiveDate and ExpirationDate
    group by 
    PolicyNumber, 
    PolicySequence,
    InsertDate,
    EffectiveDate,
    ExpirationDate
    qualify row_number() over (partition by PolicyNumber, PolicySequence order by InsertDate desc) = 1
)
select
bDate1,
ContractingFirm,
StateCode,
sum(PolicyCount) as PolicyCount, 
sum(DollarAmount) as DollarAmount
from t2
group by all
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! I'm going through this now, will report back if I can get a smooth runtime for a few years of data :D

Comment: given the `policy_table` in the sub-select has table columns AND aliases with the names `EffectiveDate` and `ExpirationDate` the ON clause of the join will use the table values, but those are not truncated, thus a policy that starts on the second of the month will be dropped by this SQL, where the original SQL will include it.

Answer (score 0):

So the sub-select is going to aggregate all policy months, BUT `basetable.date1` must be between those two date AND between some fixed `start_month` and `end_month`

This means any policy row where `ExpirationDate` is before `start_month` for the JOIN to succeed, the `basetable.date1` would have to be prior to `start_month` thus, we can add a date filter to the sub-select where `ExpirationDate >= start_month` and inversely if the `EffectiveDate` is after the `end_month` month (or [LAST_DAY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_day)) cannot be both joined to AND inside the desired window, so we can add 'EffectiveDate < dateadd('month, 1,end_month)`

giving less rows in the sub-select:

```
select
    b.date1, 
    b.contractingfirm,
    b.statecode,
    sum(pt.policycount) as policycount, 
    sum(pt.dollaramount) as dollaramount
from basetable as b
join (
    select 
        PolicyNumber,
        PolicySequence,
        InsertDate,
        date_trunc(month, EffectiveDate) as EffectiveDate, 
        date_trunc(month, ExpirationDate) as ExpirationDate, 
        sum(1) as PolicyCount, 
        sum(DollarAmount) as DollarAmount, 
    from Policy_Table
    where ExpirationDate >= '2020-01-01' 
        AND EffectiveDate < dateadd('month', 1, '2021-03-01')
    group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    qualify row_number() over (partition by PolicyNumber, PolicySequence order by InsertDate desc) = 1
) as pt 
    on b.date1 between pt.effectivedate and pt.expirationdate
where b.Date1 between '2020-01-01' and '2021-03-01'
group by 1,2,3;
```

BUT you code shows in the base table you have many state's and contracting firms, BUT you will join all policies to each state/contracting firm, because you have no filters for this. This will make the JOIN also expand much more than it should.